# How to parse a value to id onclick function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to to parse a value to `id="demo"` onclick function

Placement of **onclick function**

```
<p  onclick="myFunction()">Value.</p>
```

Where the value is parse to

```
<span id="demo"> </span>
```

***Onclick Function script**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
 var k = 30;
  document.getElementById("demo").value = $k;
}
</script>
```

I am not able to parse the value to `id="demo"` i don't where i am going wrong.

Comment: Span's dont use the `value` property, set it's `innerHTML`, `innerText`, or `textContent` property. Also your variable is `k` not `$k`

Comment: use innerHtml or innerText instead of value

Answer (score 1):

You need use `innerText` instead of `.value` for span tag, `.value` use for input tag

```
function myFunction() {
 var k = 30;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText = k;
}
```

```js
function myFunction() {
 var k = 30;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText = k;
}
```

```html
<p  onclick="myFunction()">Value.</p>


<span id="demo"> </span>
```